# Else statement isnt functioning

Tags: php

The code below displays data from database when the military number is entered correctly which is a good thing. But the bad thing and obviously the problem I'm having is it shows a blank page when it's empty or when military number is incorrect. It is suppose to echo the else statement there which is military number not found. I can't get to know what's wrong here.

```
//The html code
<form method="post" action="dutydata.php">
<input type="text" placeholder="provide unique code">
<input type="submit" name="verify">
</form>
//the php code
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "army_duty");
$set = $_POST['verify'];
if($set) {
    $show = "SELECT * FROM profile where military_number = '$set' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $show);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array(result)) {
        echo $row['military_number'];
        echo $row['first_name'];
        echo $row['last_name'];
        echo $row['paygrade'];
        echo $row['duty_status'];
        echo $row['photo'];
        echo "<br/>";
     }
}  
else {
    echo "Military Number not found";
}
?>
```

Comment: `if` should be in lower case.

Comment: this code is also open to sql injection

Comment: Oops didn't see that. Have corrected it although it isn't the issue. Still don't work

Comment: Yea I know its open to sql injection, I'm just testing for now

Comment: `if(isset($set))`

Comment: Still a blank page even with the if(isset($set))

Comment: I do not know what the values in the database are for military_number, but you first declared $set as a verification for your submit button and now you are saying where military_number = '$set' which should be true or false

Answer (score 0):

I found a few errors first the text-input has to have a name on line 2.
next check if the button isset(or clicked) on line 8, then create your variable from the text-input you name on line 2. in your while loop you left off a $ for result.

```
<form method="post" action="dutydata.php">
<input name="something" type="text" placeholder="provide unique code">
<input type="submit" name="verify">
</form>
//the php code
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "army_duty");
if(isset($_POST['verify'])) {
$set = $_POST['something'];
$show = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE military_number = '$set' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $show);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['military_number'];
    echo $row['first_name'];
    echo $row['last_name'];
    echo $row['paygrade'];
    echo $row['duty_status'];
    echo $row['photo'];
    echo "<br/>";
 }
 } else {echo "Military Number not found";}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You `if` statement is incorrect. With your `if` statement you are checking if any value is in the varaiable $set. Which it is, regardless of that value being a valid militray number or not. So it always validates TRUE and does not trigger the `else` statement.

Read http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php for more information about `if` statements.

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: Then you shouldn't leave the answer. You'll get the reputation soon, bud.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of basic errors in this code. Including the fact we use the submit button to check isset upin submission. It doesn't contain a value. What you meant to do, was set $set to what I've called "unique_code".

The code below should be sufficient for a testing solution.

//The html code

```
 //Remember if your form is on the same page as your PHP, you can set action to ""
 <form method="post" action="dutydata.php">
 <input type="text" placeholder="provide unique code" name="unique_code">
 <input type="submit" name="verify">
 </form>
```

//the php code

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "army_duty");
$set = $_POST['unique_code'];
if(isset($set)) {
$show = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE military_number = '{$set}' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $show);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['military_number'];
    echo $row['first_name'];
    echo $row['last_name'];
    echo $row['paygrade'];
    echo $row['duty_status'];
    echo $row['photo'];
    echo "<br/>";
 }
 }  
else {
echo "Military Number not found";
}
?>
```